# Обновление старой ветки master

Tags: git

имеется ветка master которая очень давно не обновлялась, а все нововведения делаются в другой ветке, например назовём ее dev.
Необходимо просто перенести все в master из dev. Обычным merge не получится, так как происходит слишком много конфликтов. Есть ли какой нить способ сделать это иначе?

Comment: Удаляете ветку master, создаете ветку master на той же позиции, что и dev

Comment: Или банальный `git checkout master; git reset --hard dev` **опасносте**

Comment: Раз есть конфликты, значит есть и изменения в master, отсутствующие в dev. Их просто выкинуть?

Comment: @user7860670, так это не делается. Технически, конечно, возможно, а вот с т.з. процесса — это тихий ужас.